# How to handle widget positions in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, layout, zend-framework2

I am going to build a site (better said e-shop) where the layout may contain dynamic content (widgets) on many positions (even in header and footer, then of course content-top, content-bottom, left and right columns).

You can think of these *widget positions* as of *banner positions* if that helps.

Now my question is: **how to handle that using ZF2???**

The point is that they may be empty, may contain one widget or even more widgets could be registered for one certain *position*. As I am new to ZF2 I cannot think of solution - whether create some layout (view) plugin and manage the *widgets* from the layout, or whether from within a controller (I guess controller is not a good idea as usually the *widgets* are once registered and should be then rendered though they may contain other dynamic content).

How did You solve similar/same problem in ZF2?

Comment: http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/zf2-widget-base-app-logic-td4657457.html this could help you out.

Comment: [How to replace the "Action" helper in ZF 2 (and make great widgetized content)](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/)

Comment: @Sam Thank You, Your link helped me. Now I now I can create view helpers (plugins) that could load all the registered *widgets* for the concrete position... Will post the solution here once I'm done.